# Conversion to the DATE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, type-conversion

I need transform this value into Date (data type) format (in MySQL). But this command is not working. Do you have any idea?

`SELECT str_to_date('25-Mar-2018 12:52 PM MDT');`

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` needs a format so the function knows on how to parse the string. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format shows the valid formats

Comment: Hi Anton, this question is definitely not a duplicate (@Shadow) but you should have specify where the problem with your format mask was. I realised that your problem could have been with that MDT part. Well unless you don't need to convert the time zones too, you can simply use this command:
select STR_TO_DATE ("25-Mar-2018 12:52 PM MDT",  "%d-%b-%Y %l:%i %p MDT");
See format masks here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: @IvanaLieska pls do not edit the code in the question beyond formatting it. Part of the problem may be that the OP did not specify any format string. You cannot possibly know. The duplicate topic shows that a format string must be applied and links to the man page.

Comment: Sounds legit but I know the person who asked this question personally and we exchanged private messages about the issue. The problem with this question isn't its duplicity but its incompleteness and vagueness which I clarified when editing it. He needed to specify that he couldn't find the appropriate format mask for the excessive chars in the string that needs to be converted to the date.